# Is it possibel to create a keyfile from PhpMyAdmin's console for File Key Management Encryption Plugin (MariaDB)?

Tags: encryption, phpmyadmin, console

As a client of my hosting provider I can not access MySQL folder to create a keyfile for MariaDB's File Key Management Encryption Plugin. I would like to encrypt tables with free tools with this limited access. I think maybe I can use PhpMyAdmin's console for this. Is it possible?

I'm using MariaDB's doc to install: [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/)

I think I could install this plugin using PhpMyAdmin's console:
[image: File Key Management Encryption Plugin]

at least I did not get an error message when I run the command from command line, but how to create a file from this console, I have no ida. Anyone ever set up database encryption using PhpMyAdmin's console?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plugin_load_add = file_key_management` directive goes in the configuration file, it isn't a direct query that can be sent to the server. So first you'll have to edit the configuration file directly to add that directive.

The next step is setting up the key file that contains the encryption keys. Again, MariaDB wants that to exist on disk as a file in the computer's file system, so phpMyAdmin or any other direct SQL command can't help with that part.

There are some system variables that can be directly edited with phpMyAdmin (such as `file_key_management_encryption_algorithm` for defining the algorithm used for the encryption) and once the encryption is properly configured you can issue the SQL command to create an encrypted table, but you'll have to do the first couple of steps outside of phpMyAdmin or any other SQL interface.

In your case specifically, you would have to ask your hosting provider to handle the configurations for you or use a different encryption method.

Comment: Many thanks! Need to find some other method to encrypt...thx!